# WPF MVVM trigger on opened popup stopping working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, triggers, popup

I have code like this:

```
<Button  x:Name="ExpandSearchCriteriaButton" Command="{Binding ExpandSearchCriteriaCommand}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StaysOpenLeaveCommand}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StaysOpenEnterCommand}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
<Popup StaysOpen="{Binding PopupStaysOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" IsOpen="{Binding PopupIsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ExpandSearchCriteriaButton}">
   //my content here
</Popup>
```

And now in C#:

```
    private void execExpandSearchCriteriaCommand()
    {
        if (!PopupIsOpen)
        {
            PopupIsOpen = true;
        }
        else
        {
            PopupIsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    private void execStaysOpenEnterCommand()
    {
        PopupStaysOpen = true;

    }

    private void execStaysOpenLeaveCommand()
    {
        PopupStaysOpen = false;
    }

    private bool _popupIsOpen;
    public bool PopupIsOpen
    {
        get { return _popupIsOpen; }
        set {
            _popupIsOpen = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PopupIsOpen");
        }
    }

    private bool _popupStaysOpen;
    public bool PopupStaysOpen
    {
        get { return _popupStaysOpen; }
        set {
            _popupStaysOpen = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PopupStaysOpen");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when my popup is opened by clicking

> ExpandSearchCriteriaButton

then

> MouseEnter

trigger should change my

> PopupStaysOpen

property to true. BThat's unfortunately not happened (tested in console) because trigger basically isn't working when I hover my button and it should, because when popup is closed, it happens. Because of that, when I click button when popup is opened, my popup disappears for while and reappears and if after that I click button it's finally working what's not my target. I want it to close for the first, not second click.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that behavior you see is correct. The trigger for Button doesn't work only if PopUp has StaysOpen=false(for StaysOpen=true it works), this means PopUp captures the mouse events for to be closed(set IsOpen to false) on first click. So if you set StaysOpen to false, the PopUp starts to catch mouse events.